# Open Graph Type Tag Facebook Application

Tags: facebook-opengraph

We have a web site www.mywebsite.com that sells widgets which implements Open Graph tags as follows:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="This is the title of the widget model" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://mywebsite/widget/67734" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://mywebsite/images/123456.JPG" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Website" />
```

We have a developer who has been asked to create a Facebook application that also sells widgets. He has asked me to change the og:type value on our website pages from "product" to "widget" so that Facebook application displays a description to the user that includes "widget" instead of "product". My understanding is that the Open Graph Protocol has a defined set of types that can be used:

http://ogp.me/#types

I'm concerned that by using a type not defined in the protocol I will degrade my ranking with Facebook, Google, or any other Open Graph subscriber. Is this correct? Shouldn't the Facebook application have the custom type value and NOT our website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 3 of Facebooks Open Graph Tutorial ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/ ) provides instructions for creating a custom type, including your own namespace. However, this documentation is for creating a facebook app and is not written to descriibe how to implement OG tags on your websites pages. After further reading I found facebook specify that OG types must be only those specified in the OG protocol. See Step 2 of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ which discusses implementing a like button:

```
"You must select a type from the list of Open Graph types."
```

In the end, the answer is to only use OG defined types for your web sites pages.